# Configure Code to forget opened files

Tags: code

I use Code a lot, and I know that restoring apps' state is a core elementary OS design principle. But I find myself bugged by the fact that every time I open Code I am presented with a huge list of tabs containing all the files I've previously opened. Any other new file I open just gets added to the list of tabs, and I often find myself having to close a huge number of tabs. Take a look at the tabs bar in the below image:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Code to not restore the previously opened files?
I used dconf-editor to explore Code's gsettings, but any change there is overwritten. I've also added Code to the *Do not collect data for the following:* apps list under the *Security and Privacy* Settings plug, all without any effect on Code's behavior.

Comment: I created a habit of closing Code using a keyboard shortcuts combo: Ctrl+W to close a file, followed by Ctrl+Q to quit. It's not ideal, but it's quite fast. There is also the option to right-click a tab and select "close all other tabs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible currently, Code calls restore_opened_documents in the activate function whenever there is no currently opened window without checking any gsettings key that would give an option. However there is a pull request to Code (https://github.com/elementary/code/pull/612) that would change it to respect the privacy settings, I expect a future update will bring this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this pull request to my attention, I will keep an eye on it.